find the index of first occurence in a string
class Solution {
public:
  int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {
    int pos = -1, i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < haystack.size(); i++) {
      if (haystack[i] == needle[0]) {
        pos = i;
        while (j < needle.size()) {
          if (needle[j] != haystack[i + j]) {
            return -1;
          }

          j++;
        }
        return pos;
      }
    }

    return pos;
  }
};

for input
haystack = "mississippi"
needle = "issip"

output should be 4 but output is coming as -1
pls tell where I went wrong

If you want to learn C++, learn C++ first (e.g. learncpp.com), if you want to do competitive coding for the sake of puzzle solving start with another language (e.g. Python). Competitive coding is about the worst way to learn a language (specifically C++). Learn to pass variables by (const) reference and learn where to find documentation like std::string::find_first_of. A lot of common "problems" have already been solved by the standard library, so look there first.

There seem to be lots of errors in your algorithm, for example haystack[i+j] is an out of bounds access (there is no guarantee that i+j is less than haystack.size()). Also the first partial failure results in the entire search being abandoned, so if if(needle[j]!=haystack[i+j]) is true you stop searching, instead you should start a new search with the next value of i. Also the value of j is not reset for each new search (this only becomes a bug when you fix the previous bug). These are all simple logic errors, you should probably start again.

It will be much easier if you write a separate function to search from position i. You can then call this function from a loop in your strStr function. Splitting a complex task into separate functions is the way to progress.

@john can you provide the correct algorithm ?

@darvince Stack overflow is not a coding service that will give you pre-made answers. This is your task to solve. Again what have you done to learn C++ first? Because you will keep running into issues if you don't. C++ will not hold your hand and prevent you from making mistakes, like out of bound array access, which will make your whole program incorrect (lookup Undefined Behavior). Maybe you want to try C++ because you heared it is the fastest language around, it is... if you are careful.

changing while (j < needle.size()) to for (int j=0; j < needle.size(); j++) and adding some bounds checking (or just change the condition in your for i loop) is probably all you need. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Just know very experienced C++ developers (like me) are kind of "tired" by Leetcode programmers asking questions here. The pattern keeps repeating itself,  failing to learn to code first, having to read badly written code (no functions, bad variable names, basic C++ error etc.)

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

What's wrong with haystack.find(needle)?

@darvince Appreciated, I was trying to help (not being mean).  I am still curious why you decided on using C++ or started competitive coding

@Peter: It is the wrong algorithm, it is std::search to search for sequence and not element.

Did you ask this question on the competitive coding site's forum?  If so, could you link to that discussion there so we can read the responses there?  If not, why not?

One thing that complicates the debugging is that -1 appears twice in your code. If you were to change return -1; to return -2; you would be able to tell which return statement is being hit, which could make it easier to see what is going wrong. A debugger would be even more effective.


The second if condition is incorrect.
You can simply return -1 at the end, if not found.
Whenever j became equal to the length of needle, we have a solution.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Solution
{
    static int strStr(const std::string &haystack, const std::string &needle)
    {
        int h = haystack.size();
        int n = needle.size();
        for (int i = 0; i <= h - n; ++i)
        {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < n && haystack[i + j] == needle[j])
            {
                ++j;
            }

            if (j == n)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Solution().strStr("mississippi", "issip") << "\n";
}


Prints
4

Maybe that's how it should be, but: strStr("mississippi", "") return 0.
